# why cant i prevent a rectangle in pygame from resizing while resizing a small image?

Tags: python, pygame

i want to enlarge a sprite in my code but the problem is that the rectangle resizes with it

i tried using the inflate function but it didnt work

```
 elif self.type == 'meteor':
            smeteor1 = pygame.image.load('graphic/Meteor1.png').convert_alpha()
            smeteor2 = pygame.image.load('graphic/Meteor1.png').convert_alpha()
            smeteor3 = pygame.image.load('graphic/Meteor3.png').convert_alpha()
            meteor1 = pygame.transform.scale_by(smeteor1, 4)
            meteor2 = pygame.transform.scale_by(smeteor2, 4)
            meteor3 = pygame.transform.scale_by(smeteor3, 4)

            self.movement = [meteor1, meteor2, meteor3]

            x_pos = 200 #random.randint(0, 800)
            y_pos = 0 #random.randint(-100, -500)
```

```
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = (x_pos,y_pos))
        if self.type == 'meteor':
            self.rect.inflate(0.5,0.5)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate on *but it didnt work*? What did it do and how does that differ from what you expected? Or mark the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76399641/2280890) below as correct if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.Rect.inflate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate) does not scale the rectangle by a factor, but resizes the rectangle by a specified number of pixel. Also `pygame.Rect.inflate` does not change the rectangle itself, but returns a new rectangle. You have to use. You must use [`pygame.Rect.inflate_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate_ip) to change the rectangle in place:

```py
w, h = self.rect.get_size()
self.rect.inflate_ip(-w//2, -h//2)
```

If you want to scale the rectangle you have to use [`pygame.Rect.scale_by`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.scale_by) or [`pygame.Rect.scale_by_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.scale_by_ip):

```py
self.rect = self.rect.scale_by(0.5, 0.5)
```

```py
self.rect.scale_by_ip(0.5, 0.5)
```